# How to access a user control in a given cell of XAML grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a XAML grid for my WPF project which  is located inside a page called MonthPage.xaml with content as below

```
    <Page x:Class="Calander.Views.pages.MonthPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calander"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">

    <Grid x:Name="month">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:day Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:day Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <local:day Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I gave the the grid an x:name "month" and in each cell I added a user control called day, here is the xaml code foy day.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Calander.day"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calander"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Background="White" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" x:Name="cellbutton"/>    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can see that there is a button in my day user control. Now my question is how can I use the x:name of my grid (I called it "month") in MonthPage.xaml.cs to change the content of the button for each day user control in the grid using c# code. My sudo code is something like this:

```
month.Children.Gridindex(column, row).day.button.content = "somestring"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find the day element in the `Grid`'s `Children` collection based on its `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` values, and then you could use the `FindName` method to get a reference to the `Button`.

Try this:

```
int row = 0;
int column = 1;
day day = month.Children.OfType<day>().FirstOrDefault(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == column);
if (day != null)
{
    Button button = day.FindName("cellbutton") as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Content = "something";
    }
}
```